# How to unnest bigquery field that is stored as a string?

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I am trying to unnest a field but something is wrong with my query.

Sample data in my table

```
'1234', '{ "id" : "123" , "items" : [ { "quantity" : 1 , "product" : { "id" : "p1" , "categories" : [ "cat1","cat2","cat3"]  }}] }'
```

There are 2 fields in the dataset: row_id and parts, where parts is a dictionary object with list items (categories) in it but datatype of a parts is string. I would like the output to be individual row for each category.

This is what I have tried but I am not getting any result back.

```
#standardSQL
with t as (
select "1234" as row_id, '{ "id" : "123" , "items" : [ { "quantity" : 1 , "product" : { "id" : "p1" , "categories" : [ "cat1","cat2","cat3"]  }}] }' as parts 
)
select row_id, _categories
from t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(parts, '$.items'), r'"categories":"(.+?)"')) _categories
```

expected result

```
id, _categories
1234, cat1
1234, cat2
1234, cat3
```

Comment: The problem is that you're expecting not to have a space after the `:` based on your regex.

Comment: I got the same result after adding a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT "1234" AS row_id, '{ "id" : "123" , "items" : [ { "quantity" : 1 , "product" : { "id" : "p1" , "categories" : [ "cat1","cat2","cat3"]  }}] }' AS parts 
)
SELECT row_id, REPLACE(_categories, '"', '') _categories
FROM t, UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(
  JSON_EXTRACT(parts, '$.items'), 
  r'"categories":\[(.+?)]'))
) _categories
```

and produces expected result

```sql
Row row_id  _categories  
1   1234    cat1     
2   1234    cat2     
3   1234    cat3
```

> Update

Above solution was mostly focused on fixing regexp used in extract - but not addressed more generic case of having multiple products. Below solution addresses such more generic case

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT "1234" AS row_id, '''{ "id" : "123" , "items" : [ 
      { "quantity" : 1 , "product" : { "id" : "p1" , "categories" : [ "cat1","cat2","cat3"]  }},
      { "quantity" : 2 , "product" : { "id" : "p2" , "categories" : [ "cat4","cat5","cat6"]  }}
    ] }''' AS parts 
)
SELECT row_id, REPLACE(category, '"', '') category
FROM t, UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(parts, r'"categories" : \[(.+?)]')) categories,
UNNEST(SPLIT(categories)) category
```

with result

```sql
Row row_id  category     
1   1234    cat1     
2   1234    cat2     
3   1234    cat3     
4   1234    cat4     
5   1234    cat5     
6   1234    cat6
```

Comment: Actually your second example is the one I need. How would I extract quantity, product id for each item? Is it possible to UNNEST items first and then UNNEST categories?

Comment: Sure. Please post new question and I (or someone else) will answer :o)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296844/how-to-unnest-multiple-arrays-in-bigquery-field-that-is-stored-as-a-string @Mikhail